# how to get checkbox data-id under current paner-body

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary checkbox-circle">
        <input data-id="680c11a0-5208-4c7b-acf9-176dedbb9878" data-share="default" type="checkbox">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary checkbox-circle">
        <input data-id="6a63886e-15be-40d5-bf95-b796383f8c05" data-share="default" type="checkbox" checked>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary checkbox-circle">
        <input data-id="b8ef0af4-eb2e-4387-8d2b-a75694911c56" data-share="default" type="checkbox" checked>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my event:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-share="default"]', function () {
            if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
                $(this).attr("checked");
                //get current panner-body children's input data-id
                var obj = $(this).parents(".panel-body");
                alert("");
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeAttr("checked");
            }
        })
```

and now,the question:
when checkbox get a click event,how to get the all the checkbox data-id value in current obj?

i hope can get all the data-id value under current panner-body,and then join them to a string,between each string with a char ','

Comment: you want all the checked checkbox ids or all check box data-ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use jquery's `map` along with `get` to achieve what you want,

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-share="default"]', function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    var obj = $(':checkbox[data-share="default"]', $(this).closest(".panel-body"));
    alert(obj.map(function() {
      return $(this).data("id");
    }).get());
  }
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/s0jgn4pr/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.panel-body .checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked', function() {
                var tempIdArr = [];
            //code for current checked check box
            tempIdArr[0] = $(this).attr('data-id');
            //end code
            //now code for all checked check-box in panel-body
            var tempLen = $('.panel-body .checkbox input[type=checkbox]').length;

            for (var i = 0; i < tempLen; i++) {
                if ($('.panel-body .checkbox').eq(i).find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked')) {
                    tempIdArr[i] = $('.panel-body .checkbox').eq(i).find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('data-id');
                }
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < tempIdArr.length; i++) {
                console.log("'data-id' :" + "\n" + tempIdArr[i]);
            }

        });
```